# Comentários fora de ordem

Tags: debate, suporte

Lendo algumas perguntas e respostas me deparei com comentários que não faziam sentido, pessoas falando com alguém que aparentemente não comentou e etc. Logo ao clicar em ver todos os comentários a ordem muda, e aparece comentários que antes estavam ocultos.

- Está certo isso?
- A lógica de como eles são ordenados é baseada em que? visto que eles
  aparentemente não são ordenados pelos mais votados.
- Não seria melhor deixá-los na ordem natural?

Achei isso muito confuso e acho que esse é o melhor lugar dialogar.

Comment: Exemplo [Antes de clicar em ver todos](https://prntscr.com/h2jr7y) [Depois de clicar em ver todos](https://prntscr.com/h2jraf)

Comment: Veja que no primeiro print da a impressão que o Bacco está falando com alguém que não está na conversa, somente ao clicar em ver todos o WictorChaves aparece na conversa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu concordo com a maioria da resposta do Guilherme Nascimento, mas tem algo que preciso indicar.

Os comentários realmente devem ser desencorajados e alguns usuários se envolvem com muita frequência em longas discussões. Quando isto acontece ou a pergunta ou a resposta geralmente não são boas. Mas há exceções. Há casos que o assunto rende mesmo.

Em todo o sistema as pessoas usam o *up* como *like*, o que ele não é. Não é no voto normal, não é no comentário e não é no chat. **O *up* sempre deveria ser usado para indicar que aquele conteúdo tem qualidade, é útil e relevante naquele contexto**.

Então, se usado certo, isto não deveria indicar problemas na conversa e sim indicar quais comentários as pessoas deveriam ler porque são complementos importantes para a resposta.

Claro que, eventualmente, ficam fora de contexto e precisa ver o todo para entender, mas pelo menos chama a atenção do que importa.

O problema todo é as pessoas acharem que gracinhas merecem um *like* e que a discussão útil seja ruído.

No SO, pelo menos em questões importantes, que ocorria mais no passado, sempre funcionou bem, aqui não funciona tanto pela perceção do *up* ser um *like*.

Embora seja um pouco esquisito, eu acho interessante essa forma de colapsar comentário potencialmente desinteressantes deixando a mostra só que chama atenção para fazer a pessoa se interessar e querer ver todo o contexto.

Pra mim o erro do sistema, e já falei várias vezes isso, é não instruir adequadamente o uso correto dos recursos onde a pessoa precisa agir em prol da comunidade. Mas a UI para expandir os comentários me parece funcional. Talvez deveria dar um indicativo a mais para os novatos como um *help* ativo. Mas a filosofia, que eu discordo, do sistema é não ser intrusivo com o usuário. Se fizessem diferente uma quantidade monumental de problemas seriam evitados.

Answer (score 9):

Acho que ninguém respondeu diretamente às tuas questões... E preferiram entrar na discussão da ferramenta em si.

Os comentários estão ordenados pela ordem que são criados e são os mais votados.

No exemplo que deste, aqueles 5 comentários são os 5 mais votados e estão ordenados por ordem de criação. Acho que era isto que realmente querias saber.

Answer (score 4):

Eu entendi o que disse, principalmente depois das imagens que linkou. Sobre o assunto devo dizer algo que alguns concordam, outros nem tanto e outros discordam completamente, comentários são quase sempre **descartáveis**, mesmo aqueles úteis.

Claro que desde que a utilidade ajude a tomar alguma decisão dentro da postagem, exemplos de comentários úteis (claro que é uma lista pequena não sei se eu conseguiria enumerar todos os tipos):

- apontar problema na resposta
- comentar possibilidade de alguma revisão ou nova versão de algo que fez a situação mudar
- evidenciar um certo ponto já dito na resposta
- algum breve debate para chegar a um consenso (este esta meio que implícito nas demais citadas)

Agora comentários como:

- Agradecimentos e elogios
- Brincadeiras divertidas
- Conversa um pouco "aleatória", mesmo que sobre o assunto

Geralmente não são considerados úteis.

Voltando ao foco, então entendendo isto, ainda sim mesmo os comentários úteis, podem ser descartáveis depois de um bom tempo, não estou nem de longe falando que isso é opinião da comunidade, mesmo no SOen (comunidade mais antiga da *rede*), a maior parte (talvez 99% deles) dos usuários normais consideram que comentários devem ser mantidos sempre, mas o que eu me refiro é como funciona *"a ferramenta"*, pro sistema ao menos os comentários são descartáveis sempre, desde que tenham cumprido seu papel, então não tem porque manter, a ideia é que eles sejam úteis para apontar algo e para ajudar em algum entendimento ou apontamento.

Como disse creio que esse é o propósito da ferramenta, mas não quer dizer que eu ou que outros usuários concordemos ou consideremos como sendo o melhor caminho, eu pessoalmente mesmo que discordasse ou concordasse, simplesmente aceito a ferramenta como ela é, no Metão deve ter sugestões de mudanças, debates do porque não concordam com comentários serem descartáveis e etc (se encontrar links relacionados eu irei postar aqui)

---

### O que isto tem haver com o problema de "ordenamento/visibilidade" dos comentários?

Isso é um pensamento um tanto quanto particular meu, mas se os comentários são descartáveis e conversas longas nos comentários são sempre desencorajados (o próprio sistema indica um link para criar uma sala automaticamente), então quando ocorre dos mais bem votados "subirem" no posicionamento é porque a conversa já se estendeu e talvez muita coisa ali já seja "descartável" ou talvez será em breve

Outra possibilidade seria que comentários com mais ups seriam interessantes que chamariam a atenção para um possível pequeno/rápido "debate" que precisa ser resolvido ali, antes de tudo ser descartável.

### Conclusão

Então para resumir, creio que o sistema vê os comentários como uma ferramenta de suporte rápido e o ordenamento assim como é hoje talvez seja para despertar o interesse para que a pessoa procure acompanhar a conversação e talvez participar da "resolução" do possível impasse e depois disto tudo o ideal seria remover tudo.

Claro que não lhe impede de sugerir mudanças, no Metão como disse devem ter pessoas que concordem contigo em alguma postagem, talvez seja interessante, talvez não, a sugestão de deixar mais "natural" talvez não despertaria tanto interesse em acompanhar, mas não dá para afirmar nada sem experimentar.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui prints significativos para o que "acho" que são os seus "comentários fora de ordem":

[image: comentários colapsados]

[image: comentários expandidos]

Note que o comentário grande do @VictorStafusa é considerado importante (tem um positivo meu até). O sistema, considerando-o importante, colocou-o na visualização rápida dos comentários. Note que ele faz alusão à minha pessoa falando de clareza/certeza do que estava lendo. Sem o contexto anterior, fica meio difícil saber o contexto de onde saiu isso...

Mas esse contexto aparece com os comentários expandidos! *Voi là!* E tem um detalhe importante nessa expansão: ele expande de tal modo que fica cronológico: mais antigos acima, mais novos abaixo.

Comment: Sim, era sobre isso mesmo, eu achei super confusa a conversa, antes de perceber como funcionava.

Comment: Fico muito agradecido por ter sido útil no seu exemplo. Entretanto, noto que a versão mobile do site tem sérios problemas de tradução (o que é assunto para uma outra pergunta completamente diferente aqui no meta, obviamente).

Comment: @VictorStafusa , esse é o app. Não tem traduções no app =P