# Qual a vantagem de se ter votos em comentários?

Tags: debate, comentários

*Pensei no título: "Votos positivos em comentários", mas como não dá pra votar negativo, claro que só podem ser positivos.*

Qual a vantagem de ter votos em comentários? Isso influencia em alguma coisa na conta, na pontuação ou é apenas para reconhecimento de que o comentário tem relevância?

### Edit

Como quase tudo (ou tudo) no SOpt é baseado em votos, estive pensando que tanto o ato de "votar" ou "receber" votos em comentários poderia surtir algum efeito prático na conta do usuário que votou e/ou na do que recebeu o voto.

Comment: Não sei quanto ao efeito na contando usuário, mas pelo menos serve para filtrar informações importantes nos comentários de outras mais supérfluas. Veja https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6500/64969.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Imagino que seja apenas isso mesmo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comentários são descartáveis, o objetivo deles é tirar alguma duvida ou indicar algo para que a postagem, seja pergunta ou seja resposta, seja melhorada ou algo do tipo.

Por ser algo descartável não faria sentido prático você ganhar score ou qualquer outra coisa por ele, mesmo que o comentário seja muito bom mesmo, daquele tipo que ganha muitos upvotes, o intuito seja que ele sirva para indicar algum problema ou dar enfase em algo na postagem o qual ele esta referenciado.

Alguns detalhes a mais seguem nesta pergunta (tem uma resposta minha nela também):

- [Comentários fora de ordem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6500/3635)

---

### Extra

Exemplo de situação aonde o comentário foi excelente:

> [image: comentário]

Na pratica foi um ótimo comentário, é um detalhe bastante relevante dentro das APIs de tempo do PHP, então minha pergunta estava assim:

> [image: antes]

E depois da edição a resposta ficou mais técnica pois contém o termo correto, ou seja tentei fazer o melhor proveito do comentário:

> [image: depois]

Logo após o comentário já teve a sua utilidade e agora ele é dispensável, **claro** que não vai ter problema mante-lo, a ideia é só mostrar como um ótimo comentário pode ser bem aproveitado.

Infelizmente ainda vejo muito comentários ótimos de gente experiente serem ignorados, teve um caso creio que do Bacco ou do Maniero, aonde explicou algo mais técnico e o AP poderia ter aproveitado aquilo para melhorar em muito sua própria resposta, mas infelizmente não foi feito nada.

Answer (score 3):

Os votos em comentários existem por um motivo prático.

Não é incomum vermos publicações com muitos comentários. A exibição de publicações é mais prioritária do que a visualização de comentários, por isso nos casos de comentários em excesso, a maior parte deles é ocultada - mas fica disponível um link para exibir mais comentários. Nesses casos, os comentários que são visíveis por padrão são os considerados mais relevantes. Uma das coisas levadas em consideração para calcular a relevância é a votação.

Existe um único impacto na sua conta gerado por votos em comentários. Você pode ganhar uma medalha:

> [Conhecedor - Deixou 10 comentários com pelo menos 5 pontos.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit)

A descrição não é clara o suficiente a meu ver. Você precisa de 10 comentários com pelo menos cinco votos em cada um para ganhar essa medalha.